# Regex adding ; to the string

Tags: regex, sharepoint, workflow

Is it normal for regex to add `;` (semicolon) in extract? For example, in SharePoint workflow I have this `[^/]*$` RegEx (with Extract selected) get the file name and put it in a collection. The RegEx puts a ; at end of the extract string.

For example: 
input: `http://www.abc.com/sites/sales/document library/2013 june sale 05450 12 (draft).pdf`

Regex: `[^/]*$`

output: `2013 june sale 05450 12 (draft).pdf;`

I think since it puts in a Collection Variable that's why it puts the trailing `;`

What are you all opinions?

Comment: I think that your question phrased as it is is more opinion based than factual. You might want to read this [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using a negative character class you can as well expand it to:

```
[^/;]*$
```

It looks a little weird since you are selecting multiple characters using the star (*) but if you claim it works for you then this one should too.